# Update as a subquery of select in myssql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, sql-insert

What i want to do is similar to mongodb `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()` method.

Is it possibe to do insert or update subquery in the SELECT statement in mysql? Baiscally select+update or insert in a single query?

Something like this maybe:

`SELECT * FROM table (UPDATE table SET field = 'value' )`

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an `UPDATE` inside a subquery in SQL.

You can only use the `SELECT` and [`VALUES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) statements in a subquery.

The way to achieve what you want in SQL is to use a transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table SET field = 'value';
SELECT * FROM table;
COMMIT;
```

You can't do everything in a single statement. In fact, that's true of most programming languages (except for LISP :-) ).